# Linux: Sending a signal to a process that does not exist

Tags: linux, signals

Upon process start, the process registers itself in the kernel module.
From kernel module, I'm calling send_sig_info to send signal to user space.

In case a BUG or kill the process no longer exists.
How can the kernel module knows that the process does not exist any more ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Should I use  find_task_by_pid_type(PIDTYPE_PID, pid) ?